# After Filling all Fields laravel sending 'required' error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to submit a form using axios post request in laravel. In this form i have 3 fields, name,age and a file called image.

here is the form

```
<form action="{{route('forms.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @{{name}}
            @csrf
        <span v-if="errors.name">@{{errors.name[0]}}</span>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name">
                <span v-if="errors.age">@{{errors.age[0]}}</span>
                <label for="age">Age:</label>
                <input type="text" name="age" id="age" v-model="age">
                <label for="image">Image:</label>
                <span v-if="errors.image">@{{errors.image[0]}}</span>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" @change="imageChanged">
                <button @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Here is my vueJs code:

```
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        name:'',
        age:'',
        image:'',
        errors:{}
    },
    methods:{
        imageChanged(e){
        app.image = e.target.files[0]
        console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        },
        submitForm(){
            const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
            const fd = new FormData(this.$data);
            fd.append('image',this.image);
        axios.post('{{route('forms.store')}}',this.fd,config).then((response)=>{

                console.log(response.data);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            //console.log(error.response.data);
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        })
        }
    }
});
```

And here is my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'age' => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        return $ext = $image->extension();
    } else {
        return "NOT OK";
    }
}
```

So here I am validating name and age. But my problem is when I fill the form and submit the form,
It sends back errors that name and age field is required.

where am I doing wrong and how to receive this data in the controller. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: print your request data and check.

Comment: It seems you are passing name and age blank in your vue JS

Comment: @RakeshSojitra So where is the problem... in my vue developer tools name and age has value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code is in error in this part. changes:

```
   axios.post('{{route('forms.store')}}',this.fd,config)
```

to:

```
   axios.post('{{route('forms.store')}}',fd,config)
```